# Basic property of conditional expectation of a function

Tags: probability

Why does this property of the conditional expectation holds?

If $X$ is a random variable $E[h(X)/X] = h(x)$

Isn't necessary any condition for the function $h(X)$?

Comment: By the way, that's not how we denote conditional expectation. And no, there is no condition on $h$, except of course that $E[h(X)\mid X]$ is well-defined, namely that $h(X)\in L^1$